# Не могу привязать recyclerView фрагмента с помощью Data Binding

Tags: android, android-data-binding

Есть макет:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</layout>
```

И фрагмент с привязкой:

```
import com.beatbox.databinding.FragmentBeatBoxBinding;

public class BeatBoxFragment extends Fragment {

    public static BeatBoxFragment newInstance() {
        return new BeatBoxFragment();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentBeatBoxBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_beat_box, container, false);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

setLayoutManager и GridLayoutManager подчёркивает красным. Как это исправить?